# Returning a typescript type to method that expects a different type but same properties does not throw error

Tags: typescript

I have 2 classes, one is named "InventoryDTO" and the other is named "Inventory".

The 2 classes store the same properties.. i.e

```
export class InventoryDto {
  id?: number
  name: string
  active?: boolean
}
```

The 2 classes are the same, but one of the classes is heavily annotated with decorators (its for the database).

If I return the Inventory to the InventoryDto - I can't get typescript to complain about it because technically its the same properties.

```
  create(dto: CreatInvenoryDto): Promise<InventoryDto> {
// this returns Inventory NOT InventoryDTO - but typescript is fine with it.
    return this.dataAccessService.create(dto) 
  }
```

I would like it to complain, am I missing something in the tsconfig, I have set strict: true

But still the same, its basically allowing me to return the type even though they are different because they are compatible..

Any way to enforce this?

Thanks

Comment: So, in short, you want TS to differ between two types that are technically the same?

Comment: Yep - 1 type is heavily annotated because of a ORM i am using., the other one isn't .. in this case they are the same - BUT for me, these are 2 different types..

But because they contain the same properties - It allows me to return it - but I don't want that.

Comment: You want nominal typing which TypeScript doesn't provide out of the box but there are ways to get similar behavior.  But right now the code here is not a [mre].  Please provide example code that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste it into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NddP6N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  There should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is probably to add a "hidden" field:

```js
class Entity {
  __type: 'entity' = 'entity';
}

class Dto {
  __type: 'dto' = 'dto';
}


class Inventory extends Entity {
  id?: number
  name: string
  active?: boolean

  constructor(name: string, id?: number, active?: boolean) {
    super();

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.active = active;
  }
}

class InventoryDto extends Dto {
  id?: number
  name: string
  active?: boolean

  constructor(name: string, id?: number, active?: boolean) {
    super();

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.active = active;
  }
}

function save(dto: InventoryDto) {
}

let inv: Inventory;
save(inv);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiB2AXAlogntA3gWAFDWgH1D0AHAUwC5oBycpVNG6AXlvpXRoG48BfPHlCQYAEUQB7LHgLEyVWgBNJzNjWUSe-QbiHgo0AJLwAbhwkAnDOQAeieopgJOGHPmjJFAfmrwArgC2AEbkFjLQ8GABChCIFsjwAObhYMAoZj7QQRISIORg8DoEwBLwsRZ+aZYAFJHR1OUJiQA0Ht6+gSEWranp5JnZufnwAJTS7gQQfhQW1SO8uhPQiAAWyBAAdJ6sbQsEBKvrG3XkOyd7+4ebvchmOzdmFwK4z3oiRqbmVuJStvbwjmgP3GBE8mX8wVC4RODTiTRSaVu-WogzyBSK0BKZTilUksxh0EaSVaYI6kO60AeyKyOTRoxB+ymMzmC3CBzWm22bE8F3ZRxOZyi5F5yw5Gyp90Rj3Cz1euAAZn54IjSoSwGZqhpqMYzEhLGgfmM3HK8ogPKZtZ89VYFhB1eRqgkTPM8EA)

Answer (score 0):

You could pick the fields you require and return only those. Ignoring TypeScript all together, if you wrote this in plain JS you'd be returning the entire inventory from the create method rather than just those fields which probably isn't what you want.

You could try something like this to retain type safety and only return the required fields:

```
create(dto: CreatInvenoryDto): Promise<InventoryDto> {
  const { id, name, active } = this.dataAccessService.create(dto)
  const inventoryDto: InventoryDto = { id, name, active }
  return inventoryDto
}
```

Comment: No, its working. but this is the problem Inventory and InventoryDTO are 2 different types - although compatible :-)

I would like typescript to shout at me when I try and return the InventoryDTO to a method that has a return type of "Inventory".

But currently it does not..

It just allows it.

Comment: `I try and return the InventoryDTO to a method that has a return type of "Inventory"` This is not the same as  `If I return the Inventory to the InventoryDto` which you mentioned in the initial question. 

TypeScript won't complain if you return an inventory to a method which says it returns an inventoryDto because like you said, it's the same properties, it's still compatible.